# Symfony cmf generate:bundle option

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

Why, conceptually, there is not inside symfony cmf app console generate bundle.
I have tried php app/console generate:bundle, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generate:bundle` bundle command is provided by [SensioGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle).

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
require:    
    ...
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"
```

Add it to your composer.json , update, register the bundle in `app/AppKernel.php` and the command will be available.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony CMF is just the Symfony2 full-stack framework with some extra bundles and extensions.

The `generate:bundle` command is a command from the [SensioGeneratorBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html). That bundle is included in the symfony standard edition, but not in the symfony cmf standard edition. Just install that bundle and you should be good to go:

```
$ php composer.phar require sensio/generator-bundle:2.3.*
```

```php
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
public function registerBundles()
{
    // ...

    if (...) {
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle()
    }
}
```